# Impossible to update Indy to latest version

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe, indy10

I've been struggling to update Indy on my Delphi XE version and simply can't achieve this task.

Tried to follow exactly the instructions on

http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.en.aspx

First i tried the option 1, that is :

> 1) use the command-line FULLD#.BAT script that corresponds to your Delphi version.

The BAT script runs, but when i open Delphi, i see no components installed.

So i tried option 2 :

> 2) Open the individual .dpk files in the IDE and compile them, in the following order:
>   IndySystemX0.dpk (in Lib\System)
>   IndyCoreX0.dpk (in Lib\Core)
>   IndyProtocolsX0.dpk (in Lib\Protocols)
>   dclIndyCoreX0.dpk (in Lib\Core)
>   dclIndyProtocolsX0.dpk (in Lib\Protocols)

The files compiled until 'IndySystem150.dpk', it returns the error below :

> [DCC Fatal Error] IndySystem150.dpk(44): F2051 Unit IdIDN was compiled with a different version of IdGlobal.IndyCheckWindowsVersion

Has anyone ever get this update done ? Any hints please ?

Thanks !

Comment: One of those folks from Indy is commonly right here on Stack Overflow, so I'd suggest you avoid that sort of remark and stay on point with your problem, or that one person might decide not to help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Always lovely and helpful, thanks :)

Comment: The BAT script compiles Indy and places the binaries where they need to be, but it does not register the compiled BPLs with the IDE. You have to do that yourself manually, by opening the IDE and going to the "Install Packages" dialog to add the 2 design-time BPLs (`dclIndyCore...` and `dclIndyProtocols...`).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, i could upgrade following the instructions, after deleting all Id*.dcu files inside Delphi folders.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, what is the right procedure to update ? Should i manually delete all dcu files inside Delphi folder ? If i just install the new packages, i'll get a lot of errors. I've been struggling to update Indy on my Delphi 2007 for 2 months , please help me :)

Comment: @delphirules that question is covered in the install documentation

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has this problem, I could fix the issues by deleting all Id*.dcu files in the folder below :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0
```

After that I could compile and install the packages.

As described on Indy installation page :

> "If Indy 10 is already installed, it needs to be uninstalled first.  Remove the pre-compiled BPL files - dclIndyCoreX0.bpl and dclIndyProtocolsX0.bpl - from the IDE via the "Components > Install Packages" dialog.  Then delete all of the existing binaries (IndySystemX0.*, IndyCoreX0.*, IndyProtocolsX0.*, dclIndyCoreX0.*, and dclIndyProtocolsX0.*) as well as delete any Indy 10 source files, if present.  Be sure to check for files in the IDE's \bin, \lib, and \source folders, \Indy subfolders, and OS system folders."

Comment: As expected, this applies with *any* package, not just Indy.

Comment: @Jerry No, you should never do this to the files installed under the program files directory.

Comment: The instructions to do so (delete old files inside Delphi) is from Indy itself : "If Indy 10 is already installed, it needs to be uninstalled first.  Remove the pre-compiled BPL files - dclIndyCoreX0.bpl and dclIndyProtocolsX0.bpl - from the IDE via the "Components > Install Packages" dialog.  Then delete all of the existing binaries (IndySystemX0.*, IndyCoreX0.*, IndyProtocolsX0.*, dclIndyCoreX0.*, and dclIndyProtocolsX0.*) as well as delete any Indy 10 source files, if present.  Be sure to check for files in the IDE's \bin, \lib, and \source folders, \Indy subfolders, and OS system folders."

Comment: That's bad advice.

Comment: @David I don't understand - you're saying that you need to keep the old DCU files which aren't needed anymore?

Comment: @JerryDodge Nevermind, David just love to bully my questions.

Comment: @Jerry You just don't modify the installation. You make sure that the indy source files are on the search path. You replace any design time packages if necessary. That's it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indy is bundled with Delphi itself. So, when upgrading Indy, you have to move/delete the bundled version or else it will conflict with the upgraded version. That includes the DCUs that are pre-installed in Delphi's installation folder

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why would it? If the search path is set correctly why would there be any conflict?